# How to write task definition based on different enviroments - dev, staging & prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, cicd, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

I have an ECS service that is running a task with one container each. Challenge is here is that I have different compute configuration based on environment.

For example in dev environment I intend to use .25cpu with .5MB memory but in production I would want to provision it 2cpu and 4GB Memory.

My thought process for the above challenge:

1. Create separate task family for each service with separate configurations and container images. For ex: my-service-dev & my-service-prod
2. Create a standard template and `sed` service name to update values

What can be the most scalable way to tackle above challenge ?

Comment: i would use one pipeline and set a variable or secret with the environment name.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator are you proposing to create task definition family based on the env like my-service-dev ? I don't if this would be scalable, as imagine of 10 services so 20 task definition family.

Comment: i kinda envision a multistage unique pipeline

Comment: @jmvcollaborator...hm. I dont know how scalable this would be. I can think of json merge using `yq merge` using json fragments ?

Comment: I use Cloud Formation templates for this, and pass everything that varies by environment as parameters.